# Finding Intermediate Temperatures of 2-Stage Counter Current Heat Exchanger

Tags: heat-transfer, heat-exchanger

I have a 2-stage counter current heat exchanger where I am given the initial temperatures for the cold and hot fluids (T<sub>H1</sub> and T<sub>C1</sub>) as well as the final temperatures (T<sub>H3</sub> and T<sub>C3</sub>). Additionally, The mass flow rates and heat capacities of both fluids are given. The effective heat transfer area of both exchangers is also stated. How do I go about solving for the temperatures in between the stages, T<sub>H2</sub> and T<sub>C2</sub>?

I tried doing an energy balance on both of the exchangers and then solving it as a system of two equations, but T<sub>H2</sub> and T<sub>C2</sub> always cancel out entirely using this method and the equation I'm left with is only in terms of known values.

I need to solve for T<sub>H2</sub> and T<sub>C2</sub> so I can calculate Q for each individual exchanger.

[image: Diagram of system]

Comment: Check out Engineering Heat Transfer by Simonson - good reference and will cover that.

Comment: Add your energy balance attempt. Do you also know heat transfer coefficients?